# Алгоритм получения массива частот элементов матрицы

Tags: алгоритм

не работает алгоритм получения матрицы частот элементов матрицы(по возрастанию)
Язык FreeMat, но можно предложить алгоритм на другом языке, там я уже разберусь)

```
X=fix(rand(3,3)*30) 
[n m] = size(X)

d = 1;
count = 0;
for i=1:n
    for j=1:m
        Z(1,d) = X(i,j);
        d = d + 1;
        count = count + 1;
    end
end
Z

S = sort(Z);
for k=1:count
    S(2,k) = 1;
end
S

D(1,1) = S(1,1);
D(2,1) = S(2,1);
m = 2;
l = 3;
while m < count
    while l < count-1
        if m==l
            D(1,m) = S(1,m);
            D(2,m) = S(2,m) + S(2,m + 1);
            m = m + 2;
            l = l + 2;
        else
            D(1,m) = S(1,m);
            D(2,m) = S(2,m);
            m = m + 1;
            l = l + 1;
        end
    end
end       
D
```

Comment: Приведите пример результата

Answer (score 1):

Заводим матрицу, в первом столбце номер строки, во втором нули, количество строк - наибольшее возможное значение (здесь, как я понимаю, 30)

Для каждого элемента матрицы инкрементируем ячейку второго столбца с соотв. индексом

```
for i=1:n
   for j=1:m
      Counts(X(i,j),2) = Counts(X(i,j),2) + 1
```

Сортируем по второму столбцу. В общем-то всё.